# Question closed as duplicate but it wasn't

Tags: discussion, specific-question, question-closure

I asked a question about comma usage: [Comma in "If in addition"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/567890/comma-in-if-in-addition)

The question was closed as a duplicate. The question that my question is a supposedly a duplicate of is about parentheses and brackets, not commas. Am I missing something?

Comment: I would assume that it is because the commas would be parenthetical commas, but I'll let people who closed it make their case.

Comment: The first person who voted to close probably did so because a part of one of the **answers** to the other question can be adapted to (arguably) answer your question, but that does not make your question a duplicate of the other **question** (which is, incidentally, itself closed). When you disagree with a reason for closing, it may, however, be more efficient to explain your reason for disagreement by commenting on the question or editing it, rather than by posing a meta-question (unless you are trying to raise some more general meta-issue).

Comment: Two points of explanation: Ashworth's answer to the dupe addresses your question of the set-off phrase (parens or not). His comment on your own question ("If in addition") also steers you right. Either way, the question is more a matter of style, and not quite cut and dry. That style quality rather than the rule of law explains why the guidance to drop commas was a comment, not a formal "answer."